# BackButton takes me to home, but return to wrong activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

I have an android app with a loginActivity and then MainActivity.

The startpoint is the loginActivity, when you first open the app you log in and then it starts the MainActivity.

I overrided onBackPressed from the MainActivity so you wont get back to loginActivity, unless you tap a logout button.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent mainActivity = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    mainActivity.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    mainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(mainActivity);
    finish();
}
```

The problem is, when i press back button, it shows the home luncher (as expected) but when i open the app again, it goes to loginActivity.

Is there any way to "bypass" the loginActivity or to tell android in which activity i stay last time?

Comment: i found someone uses moveTaskToBack(true); is that correct to use? any comments? Thankss

Comment: you can use sharedprefrences to store the name of the activity user last visited(i.e whenever any activity is resumed change the sharedprefrence with it's name). And at the main activity launch that activity directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set a preference if the user already logged in. In the LoginActivity's onCreate you can check the preference and start HomeActivity if needed + call finish() in LoginActivity. This way you don't even have to override onBackPressed later and everything will just work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the entry point of your application to the MainActivity, doing a check within that activity to see if the user is logged in, and redirect to the login activity if they are not logged in.